# addEventListener not capturing the click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm simply trying to capture when a link has been clicked but I'm not sure why my click function isn't working.

```
window.onload = function(){

var navItems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

 for(var i =0; i < navItems.length;i++){
   console.log(navItems[i]);
   navItems[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("clicked");
   },false);
 }
}
```

Comment: It should work, do you see any errors on console?

Comment: Please show the log.

Comment: @A.J nothing is shown in the console. when print things to the console outside of the listener they show up fine

Comment: @jordan - how have you included this script , is it external js or in html using script tag?

Comment: @aj figured out what i screwed up on, i left the anchor tags empty, i styled them to be circles but didn't put any text in them.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine. See the snippet below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var navItems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    console.log(navItems[i]);
    navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("clicked");
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that guys, the problem was with my html I left the anchor tags empty that's why it wasn't recording my clicks.

thanks for your input